# Fixed highlighting in tmux

Tags: terminal, fonts, colors, tmux, urxvt

I miss highlighting (reverse mode) on console since I started to use **urxvt** + **tmux** as main terminal. The highlights was replaced with with italic font *- what looks pretty cool at first -* however I can't find the one italic word in thousands non-italic when I try to search something in a `less`.

This is works properly while the terminal type is set to an `xterm*` profile (with e.g. `set -g default-terminal "xterm-color"` in *.tmux.conf*). However some shortcut can't works, apps can't get proper geometry of terminal, ... in this case.

Answer (score 12):

I have found info and solutions about it on tmux's pages:

- [tmux's mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/tmux-users/thread/20111227185155.GA5422@Xye/)
- [tmux's FAQ](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/FAQ)

> Screen's terminfo description lacks italics mode and has standout mode in its place, but using the same escape sequence that `urxvt` uses for italics. This means applications (like `vim`) looking for italics will not find it and might turn to reverse in its place, while applications (like less) asking for standout will end up with italics instead of reverse.

### [Fix 1] Replace terminfo entries and get reverse + italics

***(per user!)***

> To make applications aware that `tmux` supports italics and to use a proper escape sequence for standout, you'll need to create a new *terminfo* file with modified `sgr`, `smso`, `rmso`, `sitm` and `ritm` entries:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir $HOME/.terminfo/
> $ screen_terminfo="screen"
> $ infocmp "$screen_terminfo" | sed \
>   -e 's/^screen[^|]*|[^,]*,/screen-it|screen with italics support,/' \
>   -e 's/%?%p1%t;3%/%?%p1%t;7%/' \
>   -e 's/smso=[^,]*,/smso=\\E[7m,/' \
>   -e 's/rmso=[^,]*,/rmso=\\E[27m,/' \
>   -e '$s/$/ sitm=\\E[3m, ritm=\\E[23m,/' > /tmp/screen.terminfo
> $ tic /tmp/screen.terminfo
> ```
>
> And tell tmux to use it in *~/.tmux.conf*:
>
> ```
> set -g default-terminal "screen-it"
> ```
>
> If your terminal supports 256 colors, use:
>
> ```
> $ screen_terminfo="screen-256color"
> ```
>
> instead of "screen". See the FAQ entry about 256 colors support for more info. Also note that tmux will still display reverse video on terminals that do not support italics.
>
> If your `urxvt` cannot display italics at all, make sure you have an italics capable font enabled, for example, add to *~/.Xdefaults*:
>
> ```
> urxvt.italicFont: xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:italic:autohint=true
> ```

### [Fix 2] Simply replace italic control characters with reverse

Add this terminal override to *~/.tmux.conf*:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'rxvt-unicode*:sitm@,ritm@'
```

Comment: Fix 1 seems to work, but it's 2015, can this really be so difficult?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not find any better solution for this issue + I have stopped searching when I found this on a tmux mailing list... :(

Comment: Well, according to [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux/blob/master/FAQ#L355) tmux 2.1 should fix the behavior. So I guess this is only needed temporarily. I personally just did what the OP said and set my `default-terminal` to `xterm`.

Comment: Sometimes this is not soo good. E.g. when you have to compatible with PuTTY you can not use `xterm`, only `screeen` variants.

Comment: @user1338062 Yes, this is really sad, especially considering that `tmux` could just provide its own terminfo entry, like `screen` did for ages.

Comment: Fix 1 worked for me, but made my solarized `dircolors` disappear; I was able to fix it by adding `TERM screen-it` to the list of terminals in `~/.dircolors`.

Answer (score 6):

I run urxvt in arch linux. The op's answer did not help me. This helped me:

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/2.1/FAQ#L355-L383

---

search for `italic` and run that; then, put this in tmux config

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux"
```

don't use "tmux-256color". (try it, I suppose, but it didn't work for me.)

---

finally, add this to your rc (.zshrc, .bashrc, etc):

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

Comment: This is working for me in `2020` with `tmux 1.8` and`Putty 0.73`.

Answer (score 4):

Quicker way:

```
set -g terminal-overrides "screen.xterm-new"
```

Works without any further magic (and still heeds the warning in the tmux manual about the terminal type needing to be "screen" or a derivative thereof).

Comment: Works for me perfectly, for example `watch -n10 -d COMMAND args..` allows to detect changes now (like blanks!  How do you do italic blanks?).  I think this should be the accepted answer.  Note: When terminal already is open, use `TERM=screen.xterm-new; export TERM`